# How to prove that a limit with a piece-wise function is false

Tags: calculus, limits, piecewise-continuity

I am stumped on this practice question that I came across.

---

**It goes as follows:**

$h= 6.62607004\cdot10^{−34}$

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if }x < 0 \\
h, & \text{if }x\ge0
\end{cases}$$

Prove that  $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}=0$ is false using the epsilon/delta definition of a limit.

---

I don't understand how to do this with piece-wise functions. I also have a very difficult time even understanding how to prove limits using the epsilon delta definition.

Comment: What does $h$ represent? If $h=0$, then the limit is true.

Comment: Sorry about that. $h$ is a constant value of 6.62607004×10^−34. I forgot to put that part in but I edited it now. I have to prove that the limit is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta \lt h$, there is no $\epsilon \gt 0$ where $|x-0|\lt \epsilon $ gives $|f(x)-f(0)|\lt \delta$ for all $x$ in the interval.

Comment: Can you explain this in more depth if you don't mind?

Comment: Continuity of a function $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$: :The $\delta $, $\epsilon$ statement is: for every $\delta \gt 0$, there is an $\epsilon \gt 0$ so that for $|x-x_0|\lt \epsilon$, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt \delta$  In other words - for any interval ($\delta$) around $f(x_0)$ there is an $x$ interval $(\epsilon)$ around $x_0$ where $f(x)$ is within $\delta$ of $f(x_0)$ for all $x$.  In your case because of the jump, choosing a $\delta$ less than the jump means there are points close to $x_0$ where the $\delta$ test fails.

Comment: Alright. So you're basically saying that this limit will only exist if for every ϵ > 0 there is a δ > 0 such that if 0 < |x-0| < δ then |f(x)-0|<ϵ. Suppose ϵ = h/2, then |f(x0)-0|<(h/2) --> |0|<(h/2) --> |0-2|<(h/2)-2 --> 0<|-2|<(h/2)-2 --> 0<|-2-0|<(h/2)-2. Suppose [(h/2)-2] =δ. Didn't I just prove the limit to be true even though I am supposed to prove it to be false?

Comment: Your "proof" is flawed.  $f(0)=0$ while $f(x)=h$ for all $x\gt 0$, so $|f(x)-f(0)|\gt h/2$ for all $x$ where $\epsilon \gt x\gt 0$, for all such $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Comment: ohh. yeah that was pretty silly. i understand the question now though. thanks